# Excel - screentip without hyperlink OR stop excel from trying to fix links

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel-book where I want screenTips (like those form hyperlinks) containing added information compared to what is displayed in the cell. My current googling and attempts have so far been to add, using vba, hyperlinks that lead nowhere but have the display text set to what I want the cell to show and the screenTip set to what I want to show when hovering over the cell.

This works like I want, with one exception. Everytime I try to open the workbook excel complains about broken links, and asks if I want to fix them. If I select no, the workbook doesnt open. If I select yes, the workbook opens, fails to fix, and sets autosave to off. In order to save the workbook I need to select a path, as it seemingly has forgotten it is an already saved file. Once I do this, things work as I want.

However... I would prefer if I did not get this "fix links" prompt. That the links stay broken (as they should) and that I can autosave and CTRL+s save without needing to go through the "save as process". This mostly to not frighten off other users of the workbook.

I assume two paths to my goal are plausible:

1. Disable the excel functionality that tries to fix links for this specific workbook
2. Add screenTip using som other method than empty links.

Can anyone help me selecting 1 or 2 and guide me on the path? Google hasnt helped me so far, but I might be low on search skill atm.

Comment: How about a hyperlink that links to it's own position? - So if for example the hyperlink is in Cell A5 you set the Target of the Hyperlink to be A5.

Comment: When adding the Hyperlink per code, you can leave the address blank.

Comment: Can't you use comments?

Comment: Lord Julian: Good idea. I will try that
FunThomas: I know. It's what I did and what I believe excel is angry about when I open the workbook.
Andreas: Can I? The contenst of the cell changes by a macro. That is... i select a value, and a set of values associated with that value is populated in a range, and these values should have the screentips.

Comment: My Excel is not angry... it is not checking the links at all. How do you create them? You can, btw, add comments (both the old style comments and the threaded comments) via VBA code also.

Comment: FunThomas: How? Dont think I have heard of this. Well my excel is angry. It could be a security setup by my enterprise. As long as a company has an eager security guy, weird stuff happens with my excels. All VBA code was deleted from workbooks every now and then.